# Is there a function in R to check if there is an error in r script or in a log?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create an if statement to check whether there is any errors in my R script (or error displayed on the console) and also log files if there are to have "error" in a variable and if there isn't to have "no error" in the same variable.

I looked at is.error() however I want to check if an error is shown on the console or log file.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single-stop solution to the best of my knowledge. There are several things you can try:

1) Incorporate your script into your code and  use `tryCatch` or `try` to catch any errors. More information on error catching and debugging in R can be found [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html).

2) Execute your script in the system shell via the `system` command and inspect output caught by setting `intern=TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

You can source the script in a new environment :

```
testscript <- function(scriptpath) {
tryCatch({
          # Tests is the script runs without error
          source(scriptpath, local = new.env()) 
          message("Script OK")
         },
         error = function(cond){
           message('Script not OK')
           message(cond)
         })}
```

for example, content of script.R :

```
x <- 1
y <- 2

x + z
```

```
testscript('script.R')

Script not OK
object 'z' not found
```